# LDAP PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ldap

How do I set up postgresql 9.2 on Windows to use LDAP authentication (Windows AD server).
The LDAP and the PostgreSQL works good.

Without the LDAP, i can normaly connect to my PostgreSQL. But when i configured the LDAP authentication on my pg_hba.conf, i can't connect to it.

In pg_hba.conf I have this:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ldap   ldapserver="grp-bl.dz/dc=postgres" ldapprefix="cn=" ldapsuffix=", dc=grp-bl, dc=dz"
```

I get:

```
2015-03-04 08:43:56 GMT FATAL:  le système de bases de données se lance
2015-03-04 08:43:56 GMT LOG:  le système de bases de données a été arrêté à 2015-03-04 08:40:42 GMT
2015-03-04 08:43:56 GMT LOG:  le système de bases de données est prêt pour accepter les connexions
2015-03-04 08:43:56 GMT LOG:  lancement du processus autovacuum
2015-03-04 08:44:37 GMT FATAL:  authentification par mot de passe échouée pour l'utilisateur  « bilelovitch »
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:
host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24       ldap
"ldap://192.168.1.2/basedn;uid=;,cn=xx,dc=yy,dc=zz,dc=ca"

Make sure that your file does not have more than one form of authentication.
The pg_hba.conf records are examined sequentially for each connection attempt, the order of the records is significant

Comment: I tried it, and I got this error :
_Impossible to start the server_


`2015-03-04 15:22:07 GMT LOG:  nom d'option de l'authentification inconnu : « ldap://192.168.1.2/basedn;uid »
2015-03-04 15:22:07 GMT CONTEXTE :  ligne 82 du fichier de configuration « D:/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/pg_hba.conf »
2015-03-04 15:22:07 GMT FATAL:  n'a pas pu charger pg_hba.conf `

Comment: On ip address, you will put your ip
On basedn, you will put your domain name. and so on

Comment: échec de connexion LDAP pour l'utilisateur « cn=bilelovitch, dc=grp-bl, dc=dz » sur le serveur « grp-bl.sng » : code d'erreur 49